# Bar images issue on graph using GD libraray

Tags: php, graph, gd

I just want to know how to display bars with exact data array value on my graph using Gd library functions with for loop / for-each loop kindly reply me

helps are definitely appreciated

Confusion comment tag in this code is indicate my problem

```
$array = array(
              "Jan" => 110,
              "Feb" => 130,
              "Mar" => 215,
              "Apr" => 81,
              "May" => 310,
              "Jun" => 110,
              "Jul" => 190,
              "Aug" => 175,
              "Sep" => 850,
              "Oct" => 286,
              "Nov" => 150,
              "Dec" => 196);



$width = 600;
$height = 500;
$margin = 20;
$line_width  = $width-($margin*4)-25-15;
$line_height = $width-$margin;


$max_array_value=max($array);
$min_array_value=min($array);

$im = imagecreate($width,$height);

$red = imagecolorallocate($im,225,0,0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
$white  = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);


// Create rectangle with margin color borders 
imagefilledrectangle($im,$margin,$margin,$width-$margin,$height-$margin,$black);


// Create vertical line
for($i=25;$i<=$line_width;$i+=15){
    imageline($im,$margin,$i,$width-$margin,$i,$white);
}

// Create horizontal line
for($i=25;$i<=$line_height;$i+=15){
    imageline($im,$i,$height-$margin,$i,$margin,$white);
}

$j=480;
for($i=$min_array_value;$i<=$max_array_value;$i+=$min_array_value){
    imagestring($im,3,1,$j-=20,$i,$white);
}


//for Start Confusion here
imagefilledrectangle($im,45 ,400,$width-565,$height-20,$red);
imagefilledrectangle($im,60 ,300,$width-550,$height-20,$red);
//for End Confusion here     

header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
imagepng($im);
```

[image]

Comment: What's your specific question? How to [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) over the `$array`?

Comment: i just want to know how to display bar on graph with data array value

Comment: And what you confused about?I see two bars on your graph, so what's the problem?

Comment: problem is how to create dynamic bars with array value using Gd lib

Comment: help are definitely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your array creating bars using the data.  My code is not exact, you will have to adjust the parameters until the bars come out the way you want.  Try replacing your confusing section with something like this:

```
$n = 0;
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    imagefilledrectangle($im, ($n * 15) + 45, 400, ($n * 15 + 55), 400 - $v, $red);
    $n++;
}
```